# Cell Value Incorrect

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to get `X5` Value to change according to `L5` Value. Code only returns `620` regardless of `L5` Value, can somebody advise what I have done wrong.

```
'Change Peak Flow For Age Group

    Dim score As Integer, result As String
        score = Range("L5").Value

    If score => 35 < 40 Then
        Range("X5").Value = "620"
        Else
    If score => 40 < 45 Then
        Range("X5").Value = "610"
        Else
    If score => 45 < 50 Then
        Range("X5").Value = "600"
        Else
    If score => 50 < 55 Then
        Range("X5").Value = "580"
        Else
    If score => 55 < 60 Then
        Range("X5").Value = "560"
        Else
    If score => 60 < 65 Then
        Range("X5").Value = "550"
        Else
    If score => 65 < 70 Then
        Range("X5").Value = "525"
        Else
    If score => 70 < 75 Then
        Range("X5").Value = "490"
        Else
    If score => 75 < 79 Then
        Range("X5").Value = "450"
        Else
    If score => 80 < 85 Then
        Range("X5").Value = "430"

    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The `If score => 35 < 40 Then` syntax is wrong and your logic is flawed. `If score => 35 < 40 Then` resolves to *'If score is greater or equal to True then`*.
2. Your theoretical logic is redundant. If score is not less than 55 there is no reason to check if it is greater or equal to 55 after that.
3. A Select Case may be more appropriate here.
4. Don't use text-that-look-like-a-number when real numbers should be used.
5. There is no provision for scenarios where score is less than 35 or greater than 85

Correction:

```
if score >= 35 and score < 85 then
    If score < 40 Then
        Range("X5").Value = 620
    ElseIf score < 45 Then
        Range("X5").Value = 610
    ElseIf score < 50 Then
        Range("X5").Value = 600
    ElseIf score < 55 Then
        Range("X5").Value = 580
    ElseIf score < 60 Then
        Range("X5").Value = 560
    ElseIf score < 65 Then
        Range("X5").Value = 550
    ElseIf score < 70 Then
        Range("X5").Value = 525
    ElseIf score < 75 Then
        Range("X5").Value = 490
    ElseIf score < 79 Then
        Range("X5").Value = 450
    ElseIf score < 85 Then
        Range("X5").Value = 430
        ...
    End If
else
    Range("X5").clearcontents
end if
```

Rewrite:

```
if score >= 35 and score < 85 then
    select case true
        case score < 40
            Range("X5").Value = 620
        case score < 45
            Range("X5").Value = 610
        case score < 50
            Range("X5").Value = 600
        case score < 55
            Range("X5").Value = 580
        case score < 60
            Range("X5").Value = 560
        case score < 65
            Range("X5").Value = 550
        case score < 70
            Range("X5").Value = 525
        case score < 75
            Range("X5").Value = 490
        case score < 79
            Range("X5").Value = 450
        case score < 85
            Range("X5").Value = 430
    end select    
else
    Range("X5").clearcontents
end if
```

Comment: Your REWRITE work well, I see from you comment where my code went wrong. Thank you so much for your help very much appreciated.